# How to parse a JSON array in RAd Studio?

Tags: json, delphi, c++builder

I am trying to parse the following Json document:

```
[
  {"EventType":49,"Code":"234","EventDate":"20050202", "Result":1},
  {"EventType":48,"Code":"0120","EventDate":"20130201", "Group":"g1"}
]
```

I use the following code:

```
TJSONObject* jsonread0 = (TJSONObject*) TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(TEncoding::ASCII->GetBytes(Memo1->Lines->Text), 0);

for(int i=0;i<jsonread0->Size();i++)
{
    TJSONPair* pair = jsonread0->Get(i);
```

At this point, `pair.JsonValue`is NULL.  What do I need to do to read the values?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are not casting the JSON String properly, you must cast as an TJSONArray and then iterate over the elements.

try these samples

## Delphi

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  DBXJSON,
  System.SysUtils;

Const
StrJson =
  '['+
  '{"EventType":49,"Code":"234","EventDate":"20050202", "Result":1},'+
  '{"EventType":48,"Code":"0120","EventDate":"20130201", "Group":"g1"}'+
  ']';


procedure ParseJson;
var
  LJsonArr   : TJSONArray;
  LJsonValue : TJSONValue;
  LItem     : TJSONValue;
begin
   LJsonArr    := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(StrJson),0) as TJSONArray;
   for LJsonValue in LJsonArr do
   begin
      for LItem in TJSONArray(LJsonValue) do
        Writeln(Format('%s : %s',[TJSONPair(LItem).JsonString.Value, TJSONPair(LItem).JsonValue.Value]));
     Writeln;
   end;
end;

begin
  try
    ParseJson;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

## C++ Builder

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma hdrstop
#pragma argsused

#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <DBXJSON.hpp>
#include <iostream>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TJSONArray* LJsonArr = (TJSONArray*)TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(
    BytesOf((UnicodeString)"[{\"EventType\":49,\"Code\":\"234\",\"EventDate\":\"20050202\", \"Result\":1},  {\"EventType\":48,\"Code\":\"0120\",\"EventDate\":\"20130201\", \"Group\":\"g1\"}]"),0);
    int size = LJsonArr->Size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
      TJSONValue* LJsonValue = LJsonArr->Get(i);
      TJSONArray*  LJsonArr2 =  (TJSONArray*)LJsonValue;
      int size2 = LJsonArr2->Size();
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; ++j)
        {
          TJSONValue* LItem   = LJsonArr2->Get(j);
          TJSONPair* LPair = (TJSONPair*)LItem;
          printf("%s %s \n", (UTF8String )(LPair->JsonString->Value()).c_str(),  (UTF8String )(LPair->JsonValue->Value()).c_str());
        }
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This will return

```
EventType : 49
Code : 234
EventDate : 20050202
Result : 1

EventType : 48
Code : 0120
EventDate : 20130201
Group : g1
```

Comment: I don't think either of your code samples are correct. The input clearly represents an array of objects, but the code treats it as an array of arrays. Although the internal representation of an object might be an array of pairs, TJsonObject and TJsonArray are two unrelated classes, so they shouldn't be cast to one another. Furthermore, TJsonPair is not related to TJsonValue. Using checked type casts (`dynamic_cast` and `as`) would have exposed such mistakes at run time and compile time, respectively. This code employs the same techniques that led to the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have an invalid type cast, so what you're seeing is undefined behavior. A null result is just *one* of the many possible outcomes you could expect from this code. The `ParseJSONValue` function in this case should return a `TJsonArray`, not a `TJsonObject`. Although both classes have `Get` methods, they're not interchangeable.

The array's `Get` method returns a `TJsonValue`, not a `TJsonPair`. For this particular data, you can type-cast the value to `TJsonObject` because your data represents an array of two objects.

Use `dynamic_cast` or Delphi's `as` operator to cast from one class to another.

Answer (score 2):

dbExpress JSON parser was told to be heavyweight and sometimes problematic.

Perhaps you can choose some of the number of 3rd-party parsers, for example this shows reading array: http://code.google.com/p/superobject/wiki/first_steps

Answer (score 0):

you can get an array from a JSON string also using the JSonCBuilderBlog Library for C++Builder (free and open source):

```
UnicodeString JSONSource =
"[{\"EventType\":49,\"Code\":\"234\",\"EventDate\":\"20050202\", \"Result\":1},"
"{\"EventType\":48,\"Code\":\"0120\",\"EventDate\":\"20130201\",\"Group\":\"g1\"}]";

int           Type; 
UnicodeString Code;
UnicodeString Date;
int           Result;

TMetaObject MyArray;

MyArray.Decode(JSONSource);

for(int i=0; i < MyArray.Count(); i++)
{
    Type   = MyArray[i]["EventType"];
    Code   = MyArray[i]["Code"];
    Date   = MyArray[i]["EventDate"];
}
```

The syntax is very simple, see the following link as reference: [JSONCBuilderBlog](http://www.cbuilderblog.com/jsoncbuilderblog-class-library/) library.