# Problems while parsing a json file coming from google speech server

Tags: json, delphi, speech-recognition, access-violation

I am trying to implement google speech recognition api into my program. To do this I use the function below to parse json file sended from google server. However program sometimes works well sometimes not and gets access violation error

The code is below. Where is problem? is there anyway to check whether the json object is true format or not before parsing it?

```
function TGoogleSpeech.Convert(const stream: TStream): string;
var
  ret: string;
  js: TlkJSONobject;
begin
  try
    ret := FHttp.Post(FURL, stream);
    js := TlkJSON.ParseText(ret) as TlkJSONobject;
    try
      Result := js.Field['hypotheses'].Child[0].Field['utterance'].Value;
    finally
      js.Free;
    end;
  except
    Result := '';
  end;
end;
```

I am using [the uLKJSOn library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson/).

Comment: if which exactly line AV happens ? what is the full exact text of AV error? Implement logging, when AV happens log it to file together with the full server response. You would need to have a reproducible input data. My blind guess is that `js.Field['hypotheses'].Child[0].Field['utterance'].Value;` somewhere in the middle returns `nil` because your data does not have that field. Split the string into one dot per statement and check for nils. Then see which line generates AV. like `var1 := js.Field['hypotheses']; /next line/ var2 := var1.Child[0]; /next line/ var3 := var2.Field [..]; var4 := ..`

Comment: you also may try other json libs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864170 but i think you just have the server response without the fields you assume must exist. They i think exists only sometimes, and other times you try to extract values from nil. Just a guess

Comment: @user3057015 I have edited your question adding a link to the JSON library you use. Next time you post a question, make sure you describe all the types you use in your code.

Comment: I got the acces violation error at the line  Result := js.Field['hypotheses'].Child[0].Field['utterance'].Value;

Comment: Yes, we know that's where you get the access violation. But that statement has at least five subexpressions. Which one is the problem? Arioch suggested how you could figure it out. Stack Overflow isn't a personal debugging service. Use the debugger you got from  Embarcadero instead. Look at the value in `ret`; does it always contain what you expect?

Comment: How can I check whether that field is nil or not? And also decompiler says nothing! and even sometimes can't catch the error where exacty there is

Comment: decompiler ? decompiler is not a debugging tool!

Please read my 1st comment. You ought to split your mega-line to 5 simple lines ("divide and conquer") and good thing would be to check `varN := Var(N-1).xxxx;  if nil = varN then raise Exception.Create('varN is nil!');`  Then if exception happened - do log its text and log the google response value into text file. You have to make reproducible case. You have to nail doing certain values for `ret` and `FURL` that triggers the AV

Comment: compiler ofcourse not decompiler. I tried to say debugging with compiler I ll try to check using the method you said

Comment: is there anyway to check whether the json object is true format or not before parsing it?

Comment: Don't debug with the compiler. Debug with the debugger. There are other ways to check for a null pointer, but the obvious way works fine: `if x = nil then`. To check whether the input has the right format would ultimately require parsing it, so you may as well just check the results of parsing. If the file couldn't be parsed, then you should probably expect an exception, or whatever else your tool's documentation says it does on malformed input.

Comment: if x = nil then             doesnt work!

Comment: Yes it does. There's more to your problem that you haven't shared. What does "doesn't work" even mean?

Comment: forexample this doesnt work  if js.Field['hypotheses'].Child[0].Field['utterance'].Value= nil then dont to that etc...

Answer (score 0):

guys I found the answer:
And it  is really interesting,
when recognition is not good Googleserver sends this code as json

```
{"status":5,"id":"","hypotheses":[]}
```

it doesn't have utterance field and that cause problem.

Therefore I did this update and clean the unwanted part using the code below

```
 ret :=ansireplacetext(ret,'{"status":5,"id":"","hypotheses":[]}','');

    if (AnsiContainsText(ret,'utterance') and (length(ret)>1)  then
```

and so on..

Comment: You're still doing it wrong. Read the comments **and understand them** instead of shooting off comments (and being stubborn?). This code fails if the word 'utterance' is anywhere else, e.g in the value. The'Arioch gave you everything you need. Not voting to close the question because it still may serve others, but downvoting this answer.