# <System.JSON.hpp> Why Don't I Have It?

Tags: json, c++builder

I Have Rad Studio XE4 Enterprise but don't seem to have JSON capability.  I've seen posts with people talking about using it as far back as XE2, does anyone have any idea why I don't have the header file?  I would expect the header to be in 11.0\include\widows\rtl with the rest of the System headers but it's not there. What version did it first appear in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON was integrated into the RTL in XE6.  In earlier versions, you have to use a 3rd party implementation.

Comment: With the help of your post I determined that in XE4 the header needed is Data.DBXJSON.hpp, in XE6 this was  "mostly moved" to System.JSON.hpp. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864170/how-to-parse-a-json-array-in-rad-studio) showed me how to make it work in CBuilder, which is hard to find information.